# Using indexes with OR / GROUP BY / ORDER BY: How can I avoid filesort?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use index for the following query, but it resulted in `filesort`. 

How should I change the query &/or index to improve performance (avoid filesort)?

I tried using `UNION` but `filesort` still exists.

```
CREATE TABLE message (  
  Ms_ID INT(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  conversation INT(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  subject ENUM('E', 'F', 'S-C', 'S-A', 'R-RS', 'R-ILP', 'Re-M', 'Re-I', 'Re-R', 'O', 'SP', 'T', 'I', 'C', 'Of', 'R') DEFAULT NULL, 
  subject_ID INT(16) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, 
  sender INT(11) UNSIGNED, -- NULL=guest
  recipient INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  message VARCHAR(256), 
  status ENUM('U','R','SD', 'RD', 'SRD'), -- (unread, read, sender deleted, recipient deleted) 
  dateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (Ms_ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (sender) REFERENCES member (M_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (recipient) REFERENCES member (M_ID)


CREATE INDEX xMs_C ON message (conversation, sender, recipient, status, subject, dateTime)
CREATE INDEX xMs_D ON message (dateTime, conversation, recipient, sender, status, message)
CREATE INDEX xMs_R ON message (recipient, sender, status, dateTime, message)
CREATE INDEX xMs_S ON message (sender, recipient, status, dateTime, message)


EXPLAIN
  SELECT Ms.*, M.userName   
  FROM message Ms -- FORCE INDEX (xMs_S)
    INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID=IF (sender='3', recipient, sender)
  WHERE Ms.status!='SRD' AND ((sender='3' AND Ms.status!='SD') OR (recipient='3' AND Ms.status!='RD')) 
  GROUP BY conversation   
  ORDER BY dateTime DESC
```

---

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Ms  ALL     xMs_S   NULL    NULL    NULL    77  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  M   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   func    1   Using where
```

Comment: And your question is? Sometimes mysql decides filesort/fulltable scans will be better than using indexes.

Comment: How should I change my query &/or index to improve performance?

Comment: you're doing your join on a derived value (the result of the `if()`), as such, indexes CAN'T be used.

Comment: Issit possible to use `UNION` to use indexes?

Comment: unions have nothing to do with indexes. that's up to the individual queries within the union.

Comment: I tried this, `filesort` still occurs :: EXPLAIN

SELECT Ms.*, M.userName   FROM 

(SELECT *  FROM message WHERE sender='3' AND status NOT IN ('SRD', 'SD') 
UNION
SELECT *  FROM message WHERE recipient='3' AND status NOT IN ('SRD', 'RD') 
) Ms

INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID=IF (sender='3', recipient, sender)

GROUP BY conversation 
ORDER BY dateTime DESC

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT *

FROM

(
SELECT Ms.*, M.userName   
FROM message Ms -- FORCE INDEX (xMs_S)
    INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID = recipient
  WHERE Ms.status!='SRD' AND sender='3' AND Ms.status!='SD' 

UNION ALL

SELECT Ms.*, M.userName   
FROM message Ms -- FORCE INDEX (xMs_S)
    INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID = sender
  WHERE Ms.status!='SRD' recipient='3' AND Ms.status!='RD'
) a

GROUP BY conversation   
ORDER BY dateTime DESC;
```

Comment: Yes, tried that, but I also need the `GROUP BY` & `ORDER BY` the `UNION`-ed results

Comment: Which still gimme `filesort`! =(

Comment: If you had one index on status and recipient and a separate one on status and sender it might use the index.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your grouping?  You are grouping by conversation but are showing all fields from the message table and the member's username.  Since you are grouping by conversation, you will just show all info from the first message in the group.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Well I have (recipient, sender, status, dateTime, message) & (sender, recipient, status, dateTime, message)

EXPLAIN

SELECT Ms.*   FROM 

(SELECT Ms.*, M.userName  FROM message Ms
INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID=recipient
WHERE sender='3' AND Ms.status NOT IN ('SRD', 'SD') 

UNION

SELECT Ms.*, M.userName  FROM message Ms
INNER JOIN member M ON M_ID=sender
WHERE recipient='3' AND Ms.status NOT IN ('SRD', 'RD') 
) Ms

GROUP BY conversation 
ORDER BY dateTime DESC 

results :: Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Yes! I wanna get the latest message in each conversation

Comment: It's not going to use either of those.  You need one index where Sender is the first field and status is the second, and one where Recipient is the first field and status is the second.  If there are any other fields before or between these fields in the index, it will not use them.

Comment: 1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 59  Using temporary; Using filesort
2  DERIVED  Ms  ref  xMs_S,xMs_R  xMs_S  5   42  Using where
2  DERIVED  M  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  merchant_bar.Ms.recipient  1  
3  UNION  Ms  ref  xMs_S,xMs_R  xMs_R  4   3  Using where
3  UNION  M  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  merchant_bar.Ms.sender  1  
NULL UNION RESULT  <union2,3>  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: The derived table can't use indexes.  It's derived.  I think that may be the best you're going to do.  Is it slow?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` require sorting; there's simply no way for MySQL to produce the results you're asking for without sorting the data.  *Using filesort* means MySQL is sorting your data table. Go ahead and rage against the machine, but it is doing what you asked it to do.

It could possibly use an index sort instead of a filesort, but you're grouping by `conversation`. That column doesn't appear as the first component of any index you've shown in your question.

What has happened is the server must gather your joined data into a temporary table to sort it.  Check out MySQL / MariaDB developer's Sergey Petrunia's blog for an explanation of how this works.

http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24

You're also including a lot of hidden columns in your `GROUP BY` statement.  The ability to `GROUP BY` hidden columns is a (mis)feature that's distinctive to MySQL.  These hidden columns may be one of the reasons the server is gathering your joined data and then sorting it in a different step.  Read this page of the MySQL manual to learn more about this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Other than seeing *Using filesort* in your `EXPLAIN` output, how do you know you're having performance problems?  How much data are you handling? How long is it taking?

Comment: Actually I do (conversation, sender, recipient, status, subject, dateTime). But since there's `ORDER BY`, so I created another index as shown above (the previous still exists)